# Using a D Language DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, function, dll, call, d

I'm doing a C# project for school that uses C, C++, C#, and D. Maybe I'm just using the wrong terms in google, but I can't seem to find any method on how to call functions from a D dll in C#. Does one exist? Or will I need to use a roundabout method of using the code?

Edit: Just a bit more info: [I used this example for creating the dll](http://wiki.dlang.org/Win32_DLLs_in_D), but after that I'm stuck.

Comment: He mean the D programming language :-)

Comment: @Niels oh... didn't know about it

Comment: @ItamarGreen So, you will be surprised ! There is almost all programming concepts in a one language :-D

Comment: I should ask, why do you even want to call D assemblies from C# ?

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf I'm making the program in C#, plus I wanted to see if I could use all four in one program. Also I'm reading the stuff you posted in your answer, we'll see how it goes!

Comment: This is a good [PDF about the D programming language](http://www.lunesu.com/uploads/ModernCOMProgramminginD.pdf).

Comment: If you followed the "DLLs with a C interface" section you built a DLL with a standard C interface. To call e.g. the "dllprint" function, call it like you would call a C function from C#: Either with P/Invoke or with LoadLibrary https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much no different than making a dll in C or C++.

When calling it, just make sure the calling convention matches and you should be good to go with normal PInvoke.

I believe you have to export as C though by declaring your functions with `export (C)`.

You may also have to initialize the D runtime. See: http://dlang.org/phobos/core_runtime.html#.rt_init